# I want to delete all subcategory from database automatically when I delete the parent category

Tags: php, mysql

When a parent category(e.g., Architecture, Art and Culture) is dropped from the database,  I want all subcategories under the parent category to be dropped from the database. I don't know how to write a query for this.

I am using PHP and MySQL database, the category and subcategory are two separate tables, the snapshots of the tables are given below.

*Category Table*

[image]

*Subcategory Table*

[image]

Comment: Next time post your tables as text instead of images by using the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: Please keep in mind that if you will have children, items, call it what you want them, in these categories or subcategories you will have zombi items, ie unassociated items. One option is to delete these as well or migrate the items to another category. Regarding the delete you may join them as well. `DELETE c, s FROM category AS c JOIN subcategory AS s ON c.cat_id = s.parent_id`. Another tip I could add is merge the two tables cat_id, parent_id, cat_name, but will require some joining sql

Comment: PS: if you will have items in the subcategories then you will have a hard time associating it with the parent category. This is the reason why I suggested to merge the 2 tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE

```
ALTER TABLE subcategory ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_parent(parent_id)
REFERENCES category(cat_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This automatically deletes subcategories when the parent is deleted. Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html for more information.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You :)

Comment: You are welcome @SanchitGupta , you are having the same problem I presume

Comment: I already tried to up-vote the comment but I don't have enough reputation as I am a complete newbie here. In future hopefully. :)

Comment: no worries about the upvote. Here's one from me to start oyou on your way. But if the answer worked, please be so kind as to mark it as correct by ticking the tick mark so that it may be usefull to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use foreign key here. so if you delete parent id then it child will be delete automatically

```
ALTER TABLE subcategory ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_parent(parent_id)
REFERENCES category(cat_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not in the query; your sql should be a normal `DELETE` query.

What you need to do is configure the `FOREIGN KEY` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

**See this tutorial:**
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: Thank you so much.. This link really explains the one to many relationship clearly. I have now a clear idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 1;
DELETE FROM category WHERE cat_id = $id;
DELETE FROM subcategory WHERE parent_id = $id;
```

if added DELETE CASCADE

```
$id = 1;
DELETE FROM category WHERE cat_id = $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a relation between `category and subcategory`. I mean `category` has many `subcategories`. So it should be `one-to-many` relationships. And when you will set this relation you have to use onDelete `cascade`. So once the category will delete then the subcategory will delete automatic.